# Naive implementation of Burst Balloon

Tags: algorithm, programming-challenge, haskell

As part of learning Haskell, I'm solving few problems, usually solved imperatively.

I've come up with a naive solution for the problem [described](https://leetcode.com/problems/burst-balloons/description/) [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/galstertechblog/2016/03/31/burst-balloons/), which is to find a sequence in which to burst a row of balloons that will earn the maximum number of coins. Each time balloon \$i\$ is burst, we earn \$C_{i-1} \cdot C_i \cdot C_{i+1}\$ coins, then balloons \$i-1\$ and \$i+1\$ become adjacent to each other.

I would like to get few comments on the naive implementation below before solving it using dynamic programming.

What I'm looking for is:

1. Correctness
2. Program structure
3. Idiomatic Haskell
4. Any other higher order functions that can be used
5. Other optimizations that can be done

```
import qualified Data.List as List (permutations)

burst :: [Int] -> (Int, [Int])
burst = burstNaive

burstNaive :: [Int] -> (Int, [Int])
burstNaive = foldl (\a@(aVal,_) e@(eVal,_) -> if eVal > aVal then e else a) (0, []) . allOrders

allOrders :: [Int] -> [(Int, [Int])]
allOrders []       = []
allOrders l@(x:xs) = map (\p -> (flip withOrder l p, p))$ List.permutations [0..length l - 1]

type IndexOrder = [Int]
withOrder :: IndexOrder -> [Int] -> Int
withOrder []     _  = 0
withOrder (i:is) xs = left * (xs !! i) * right + withOrder adjust xss
  where
    xss = remAt i
    adjust = map (\index -> if index > i then index - 1 else index) is
    left  = if i == 0 then 1 else xs !! (i-1)
    right = if i == (length xs - 1) then 1 else xs !! (i+1)
    remAt index = let (f,s) = splitAt index xs in f ++ drop 1 s
```

Sample Output:

```
Prelude> :l Balloon.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Balloon          ( Balloon.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
*Balloon> burst [3,1,5,8]
(167,[1,2,0,3])
*Balloon>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, it's great that you've used type signatures for all your functions. Also, all used functionality is hidden away in helpers, which is also a plus.

---

We can rewrite `burstNative` with  `maximumBy` and `comparing`:

```
import Data.List (maximumBy)
import Data.Ord (comparing)

burstNaive :: [Int] -> (Int, IndexOrder)
burstNaive [] = (0, [])
burstNaive xs = maximumBy (comparing fst) . allOrders $ xs
```

While it's possible to use `((0, []) . allOrders` instead of the pattern matching, matching makes the base case more visible.

Also, this is a perfect spot to use `IndexOrder` instead of `[Int]`.

---

In `withOrder` we traverse the list too often. Since lists are just forward linked lists in Haskell, we have to walk through the list four times, once for `left`, once for `right`, once for `xs !! i` and once for `splitAt`. That's a handful. So instead let's do that only once:

```
-- def: default value if list is too short/at end
moveAtStencil3 :: a -> Int -> [a] -> ((a,a,a), [a])
moveAtStencil3 def i xs 
   | i < 1     = let (m:r:_) = xs in ((def, m, r), drop 1 xs)
   | otherwise = let (as,bs) = splitAt (i - 1) xs
                     (l:m:r) = take 3 (bs ++ repeat def) 
                 in ((l,m,r), as ++ (l : r : drop 3 bs)

withOrder :: IndexOrder -> [Int] -> Int
withOrder []     _  = 0
withOrder (i:is) xs = left * middle * right + withOrder adjusted xss
  where
    ((left, middle, right), xss) = moveAtStencil3 1 i xs
    adjusted = map (\index -> if index > i then index - 1 else index) is
```

While we're at it, I renamed `adjust` to `adjusted`. Verbs (`adjust`) are usually functions, whereas `adjusted` is a list.

---

We could replace `permutations` in `allOrders` with recursion, but that wouldn't change much.