# Solving the Burst Balloon problem using Dynamic Programming

Tags: algorithm, programming-challenge, haskell, dynamic-programming

Continuing where I left off [previously](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/195006/haskell-naive-implementation-of-burst-balloon) to solve the problem [described](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/galstertechblog/2016/03/31/burst-balloons/) [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/burst-balloons/description/), I've now solved the same using dynamic programming ([following Tikhon Jelvis blog on DP](http://jelv.is/blog/Lazy-Dynamic-Programming/)).

To refresh, the challenge is to find a sequence in which to burst a row of balloons that will earn the maximum number of coins. Each time balloon \$i\$ is burst, we earn \$C_{i-1} \cdot C_i \cdot C_{i+1}\$ coins, then balloons \$i-1\$ and \$i+1\$ become adjacent to each other.

```
import qualified Data.Array as Array


burstDP :: [Int] -> Int
burstDP l = go 1 len
  where
    go left right | left <= right = maximum [ds Array.! (left, k-1)
                                            + ds Array.! (k+1, right)
                                            + b (left-1)*b k*b (right+1) | k <- [left..right]]
                  | otherwise    = 0
    len = length l
    ds = Array.listArray bounds
           [go m n | (m, n) <- Array.range bounds]
    bounds = ((0,0), (len+1, len+1))
    l' = Array.listArray (0, len-1) l
    b i = if i == 0 || i == len+1 then 1 else l' Array.! (i-1)
```

I'm looking for:

1. Correctness
2. Program structure
3. Idiomatic Haskell
4. Any other higher order functions that can be used
5. Other optimizations that can be done

Comment: This code isn't complete. What's `Array`?

Comment: @Zeta Data.Array imported from the array package

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `Array` for memoization can be extracted into `array-memoize`.

If one can stop instead of having negative balloons decrease score, `go` can be condensed into one case.

```
import Data.Function.ArrayMemoize (arrayMemoFix)
import Data.Array ((!), listArray)

burstDP :: [Int] -> Int
burstDP l = arrayMemoFix ((0,0), (len+1, len+1)) go (1, len) where
  go ds (left, right) = maximum $ 0 :
    [ds (left, k-1) + ds (k+1, right) + b (left-1)*b k*b (right+1) | k <- [left..right]]
  b = (!) $ listArray (0, len+1) (1 : l ++ [1])
  len = length l
```

If you don't care too much about performance, we can also `memoize` directly on the balloon list:

```
burstDP :: [Int] -> Int
burstDP = memoFix3 go 1 1 where go ds l r b = maximum
  [ ds left l x + ds right x r + l*x*r
  | (left, x:right) <- zip (inits b) (tails b)
  ]
```